# Spring JPA always caches data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i am not familiar as to how Spring JPA do caching on my queried database data.

Here is my scenario. I have a thread that always queries data from database. Then this database table data is updated from other module (i.e adding of data via REST-API request).

Now, my thread keeps on handling the same data every cycle, it does not get the updated data from database. Now, i have read that it caches the data but i do not know (or i have no idea) as to how to NOT cache it since i need the real time data.

Here is my source of the Thread. As seen below i am calling `em.clear()` as describe on other resources to clear the cache. However, it does not work.

Also tried moving `em.clear()` after `getMyRepo()` method call, but an error `could not initialize proxy - no Session` occurs.

Here is `@Entity`, Sorry i can't post the source as it has sensitive information. I just post the diagram indicating its relationship.

[image]

**MyThread.java**

```
@Component
@Transactional
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyThread.class);

    private long myRepo_id;
    private boolean interrupt = false;

    @Autowired
    private MyProperties prop;

    @Autowired
    MyRepoRepository repo;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!interrupt) {
            try {
                MyEntity entity = getMyRepo(myRepo_id);
                
                entity.stream().forEach(entry -> {
                    logger.info("This is my updated data from db: {}", entry.getMessage());
                });
                
                em.clear();
                
                Thread.sleep(prop.getProcessingInterval());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                logger.error("Error Occured");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error Occured");
            }
        }
    }

    private MyRepo getMyRepo(long id) {
        return repo.findById(id).get();
    }

    public void interrupt() {
        this.interrupt = true;
    }

    public void setMyRepoId(long myRepo_id) {
        this.myRepo_id = myRepo_id;
    }
}
```

**AppEventConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class AppEventConfiguration {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppEventConfiguration.class);
        
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myThread")
    private TaskExecutor executor;
    
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void onApplicationReadyEvent() {
        MyThread t = this.context.getBean(MyRunnableThread.class);
        t.setMyId(dto.getId());
        executor.execute(t); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Session is bound to the threadlocal how did you open new thread and start it?

Comment: Simpler way is to use jdbcTemplate in spring. There is no cache and you can query anytime

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez via ThreadPoolExecutor, See updated post